# How do I sample Simultaneous Sums of Gamma-Distributed Variables?

Tags: sampling, multivariate-analysis, gamma-distribution, sum

Suppose I have 7 variables $y_i$ sampled from $Gamm(a,1)$, with $a>0$. Now, I define
$$x_1 = y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4,$$
$$x_2 = y_1+y_2+y_5+y_6,$$
$$x_3 = y_1+y_3+y_5+y_7$$
What is the distribution of $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3$? Can I somehow sample these without sampling $y_i$? I know that sums of gamma-distributed variables are also gamma-distributed, but the connected natures of the $y_i$ variables in the $x_i$ sums means I cannot sample $x_i$ with a gamma distribution.

Comment: Each of the $x_i$ is $\mathrm{Gamma}(4a,1)$ distributed, but given the correlations my guess is that starting with the $y_j$ is the easiest way to do it

Comment: If $X \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(a, s)$ and independently $Y\sim\mathsf{Gamma}(b, s),$ then $X+Y \sim \mathsf{Gamma}(a+b, s).$ Proof easy with moment generating functions. However, if the second parameters are not the same, then it's more complicated.